# How to read data from Firebase to android studio in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code :

[image]

Below is my database:

[image]

I want to read data from the database but it fails.

Comment: Don't post your code as Image , please write it to be more clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, all the IDs under the "users" node are actually pushed IDs that are provided by DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method, and **not** UIDs that are coming from the authentication process. So when you are adding a "User" object to the database, don't use the "push()" method, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
DatabaseReference uidRef = usersRef.child(uid);
uidRef.setValue(userObj);
```

To get the data back, your actual code may remain unchanged. It will work perfectly fine.

**P.S.** Stop ignoring errors. Use:

```
Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
```

In your "onCancelled()" method instead of blindly considering that everything works fine. The "databaseError" object might contain useful information that can be used to debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

**First you should copy the code instead of the photo**

For the ans

You should add the Query variable

```
DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users").child(userid);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
            String phone = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
    
    profileName.setText(name);
    profileEmail.setText(email);
    profilePhone.setText(phone);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("firebasename", "error");
        }
    });
```